# For loop on time series to add forecast values to original data frame

Tags: r, for-loop, time-series, forecasting, forecast

I have a data set called transactions_query:

```
 Index   Date                     Number_transactions
 500     2017-05-17               20546
```

I am using an ARIMA model to forecast values on this data, which is saved to transactions_query_fit (which is a forecast object). Here is a sample row

```
            Point Forecast    Lo 80     Hi 80    
2018.3217   42769.17          39160.82  46710.00

Lo 95     Hi 95
37375.59  48941.08
```

What I want to do is append this forecast to the original data

I've tried the following:

Convert the forecast to a data frame and then a matrix:

```
transaction_query_fit<- as.data.frame(transaction_query_fit)
transaction_query_fit<- as.matrix(transaction_query_fit)
```

Doing so should allow me to then rbind the forecast to the transaction_query data frame?

I thought about a FOR LOOP that would generate the daily transaction dates for the forecast by taking the last row from the transaction_query data frame

```
latest_transaction <- tail(transactions_query,1)
latest_transaction <- latest_transaction[,1]

row<- 0
for (i in transaction_query_fit[1:nrow(transaction_query_fit),1]) 
{
row[i] <- row[i] + 1
transaction_query_fit$date <- latest_transaction + row[i]
}
```

But this isn't working at all. I get the error "Argument of length 0". It seems that the loop is only able to apply

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

---EDIT---

I'm doing testing with confusing results:

```
row<- 1
for (i in transaction_query_fit[1:nrow(transaction_query_fit),1]) {
  row[i] <- row[i] + 1
  print(row[i])
}
```

Prints out "[1] NA"

Which I don't understand why

It's like the index isn't available as if I hadn't converted to a matrix before running the loop

Running:

```
 transactions_query_fit[1:nrow(transactions_query_fit),1]
```

Gives a good looking and nicely formatted output:

```
[1] 42769.17 42184.20 41580.65 44223.21 31672.88 24786.25 35532.48 36102.99
```

But why is the loop giving NA's?!

Comment: I think the problem is that you initialize "row" to be zero, and then try to access its "i"th entry where "i" is the first value of "transaction_query_fit".

Comment: Thanks for the idea, still throwing the same error i'm afraid

Comment: why not just bind the data frames together with `cbind()`

Comment: That's what I want to be able to do. But the issue is is that the forecast is a forecast object, with no dates available. I need to convert it to a dataframe, then add a dates column before I can bind

Comment: That's where i'm getting stuck here. Thanks for your response